# maven-shade-plugin class path resource issue

Tags: java, spring, maven

I have a spring project which is dependent on other projects. So, I build a jar using maven-shade-plugin so that I can run the jar from windows or linux (cmd/terminal) just by putting the jar in a folder along with log4j.xml and .properties file. On running the jar 
E:\Pan\Locator\dec1\New folder>java -jar Locator5.1.5.jar
I am getting the following exception :

```
org.springframework.beans.factory.parsing.BeanDefinitionParsingException: Configuration problem: Unable to locate Spring NamespaceHandler for XML schema namespace
[http://www.springframework.org/schema/tx]
Offending resource: class path resource [applicationContext-locator.xml]

        at org.springframework.beans.factory.parsing.FailFastProblemReporter.error(FailFastProblemReporter.java:68)
        at org.springframework.beans.factory.parsing.ReaderContext.error(ReaderContext.java:85)
        at org.springframework.beans.factory.parsing.ReaderContext.error(ReaderContext.java:80)
        at org.springframework.beans.factory.xml.BeanDefinitionParserDelegate.error(BeanDefinitionParserDelegate.java:318)
        at org.springframework.beans.factory.xml.BeanDefinitionParserDelegate.parseCustomElement(BeanDefinitionParserDelegate.java:1435)
        at org.springframework.beans.factory.xml.BeanDefinitionParserDelegate.parseCustomElement(BeanDefinitionParserDelegate.java:1428)
        at org.springframework.beans.factory.xml.DefaultBeanDefinitionDocumentReader.parseBeanDefinitions(DefaultBeanDefinitionDocumentReader.java:185)
        at org.springframework.beans.factory.xml.DefaultBeanDefinitionDocumentReader.doRegisterBeanDefinitions(DefaultBeanDefinitionDocumentReader.java:139)
        at org.springframework.beans.factory.xml.DefaultBeanDefinitionDocumentReader.registerBeanDefinitions(DefaultBeanDefinitionDocumentReader.java:108)
        at org.springframework.beans.factory.xml.XmlBeanDefinitionReader.registerBeanDefinitions(XmlBeanDefinitionReader.java:493)
        at org.springframework.beans.factory.xml.XmlBeanDefinitionReader.doLoadBeanDefinitions(XmlBeanDefinitionReader.java:390)
        at org.springframework.beans.factory.xml.XmlBeanDefinitionReader.loadBeanDefinitions(XmlBeanDefinitionReader.java:334)
        at org.springframework.beans.factory.xml.XmlBeanDefinitionReader.loadBeanDefinitions(XmlBeanDefinitionReader.java:302)
        at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanDefinitionReader.loadBeanDefinitions(AbstractBeanDefinitionReader.java:174)
        at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanDefinitionReader.loadBeanDefinitions(AbstractBeanDefinitionReader.java:209)
        at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanDefinitionReader.loadBeanDefinitions(AbstractBeanDefinitionReader.java:180)
        at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanDefinitionReader.loadBeanDefinitions(AbstractBeanDefinitionReader.java:243)
        at org.springframework.context.support.AbstractXmlApplicationContext.loadBeanDefinitions(AbstractXmlApplicationContext.java:127)
        at org.springframework.context.support.AbstractXmlApplicationContext.loadBeanDefinitions(AbstractXmlApplicationContext.java:93)
        at org.springframework.context.support.AbstractRefreshableApplicationContext.refreshBeanFactory(AbstractRefreshableApplicationContext.java:130)
        at org.springframework.context.support.AbstractApplicationContext.obtainFreshBeanFactory(AbstractApplicationContext.java:537)
        at org.springframework.context.support.AbstractApplicationContext.refresh(AbstractApplicationContext.java:451)
        at org.springframework.context.support.ClassPathXmlApplicationContext.<init>(ClassPathXmlApplicationContext.java:139)
        at org.springframework.context.support.ClassPathXmlApplicationContext.<init>(ClassPathXmlApplicationContext.java:83)
        at com.abc.zd.lt.Locator.main(Locator.java:63)
```

I have applicationContext-locator.xml, locator.properties and log4j.xml file in src/main/resources folder in the project. On extracting the jar I can see applicationContext-locator.xml inside the Locator5.1.5 folder

My pom.xml entries

```
<build>
            <plugins>
                <plugin>
                    <groupId>org.apache.maven.plugins</groupId>
                    <artifactId>maven-shade-plugin</artifactId>
                    <executions>
                        <execution>
                            <phase>package</phase>
                            <goals>
                                <goal>shade</goal>
                            </goals>
                            <configuration>
                                <finalName>Locator5.1.5</finalName>
                                <transformers>
                                    <transformer
                                        implementation="org.apache.maven.plugins.shade.resource.ManifestResourceTransformer">
                                        <manifestEntries>
                                            <Main-Class>com.abc.zd.lt.Locator</Main-Class>
                                            <Class-Path>./</Class-Path>
                                            <Build-Number>1</Build-Number>
                                        </manifestEntries>
                                    </transformer>
                                    <transformer
                                        implementation="org.apache.maven.plugins.shade.resource.DontIncludeResourceTransformer">
                                        <resource>log4j.xml</resource>
                                        <resource>.properties</resource>
                                    </transformer>
                                </transformers>
                                <filters>
                                    <filter>
                                        <artifact>*:*</artifact>
                                        <excludes>
                                            <exclude>META-INF/*.SF</exclude>
                                            <exclude>META-INF/*.DSA</exclude>
                                            <exclude>META-INF/*.RSA</exclude>
                                        </excludes>
                                    </filter>
                                </filters>
                            </configuration>
                        </execution>
                    </executions>
                </plugin>
                <plugin>
                    <groupId>org.apache.maven.plugins</groupId>
                    <artifactId>maven-compiler-plugin</artifactId>
                    <version>3.1</version>
                    <configuration>
                        <source>1.7</source>
                        <target>1.7</target>
                    </configuration>
                </plugin>
            </plugins>
        </build>
```

I extracted the jar and  my MANIFEST looks is

```
Manifest-Version: 1.0
Build-Number: 1
Class-Path: /
Build-Jdk: 1.7.0_55
Built-By: pan
Created-By: Apache Maven
Main-Class: com.abc.zd.lt.Locator
Archiver-Version: Plexus Archiver
```

Not sure why classpath is / even when I have provided ./.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Finally, figured it out. For all maven-shade-plugin spring NameSpaceHandler related issue need to add following lines in the plugin

```
     <transformer implementation="org.apache.maven.plugins.shade.resource.AppendingTransformer">
                                            <resource>META-INF/spring.handlers</resource>
                                        </transformer>

<transformer implementation="org.apache.maven.plugins.shade.resource.AppendingTransformer">
                                            <resource>META-INF/spring.schemas</resource>
                                        </transformer>
```